# How to get value or set values In Bootstrap Yes no switch Button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

in Boot Strap style Yes No Switch button , how to set values . if Yes means true and if No means false.

```
<label class="pull-right inline">
  <small class="muted smaller-90"></small>
  <input id="id-Kitchen" checked="" type="checkbox" class="ace ace-switch ace-switch-5" />
  <span class="lbl middle"></span>
</label>

 $('#id-Kitchen').attr('checked', 'checked').on('click', function () {
    alert('asd');
    $('#default-buttons .btn').toggleClass('no-border');
 });
```

Comment: That will depend on the plugin you are using. I see you are using one called `ace`? I use Bootstrap Switch - [link](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org) and the documentation is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript this is what you would do.

```
$('#id-Kitchen').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```